# ¿Las discusiones en el chat tienen notificaciones similares a los comentarios?

Tags: soporte, chat, notificaciones

Hace aproximadamente 2 meses estuve en un chat de discusión con otro usuario acerca de una pregunta y al iniciar la discusión, esperé a que el usuario respondiera y como tomó bastante tiempo, cerré la pestaña y continué haciendo mis actividades como de costumbre.

Después de varias horas, me preguntaba si tal vez ya había respondido y entré al chat de discusión para saber si había sido así y me percaté que la respuesta del usuario estaba ahí (exactamente 18 horas más tarde), sin embargo, **no recibí ningún tipo de notificación acerca del nuevo mensaje.**

Horas más adelante, el usuario dejó de responder, y lástimosamente olvidé esa discusión, hasta 4 días más tarde, donde entré al chat de discusión nuevamente y **¡ahí estaba su mensaje!.**

Hasta el día de hoy, el chat de discusión fue congelado por inactividad, y el usuario no respondió más.

Cabe recalcar que la forma que utilizaba para ingresar al chat de discusión era **buscando la pregunta del usuario** y **localizando el comentario para entrar a la discusión.**

Me surge esa incógnita, tal vez es algun procedimiento que estoy omitiendo, debido a que soy relativamente nuevo con las funciones de StackOverflow, he visto que la pestaña de chat permite activar notificaciones de escritorio:

[image: img]

Pero si la pestaña se cierra (en mi caso por realizar mis actividades):

- **¿Cómo puedo ser notificado de nuevos mensajes del chat de discusión?** (por ejemplo, en mi bandeja de entrada)
- O de ser imposible o no recomendable, **¿cómo podría mejorar esto?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cuando te **mencionen** en una sala de chat (te hacen un ping), te va a llegar una notificación en tu bandeja de entrada. Para eso, se debe cumplir que:

- te mencionen usando `@nombre`.

  - El `@nombre` también se genera automáticamente cuando alguien responde haciendo click en <kbd>↳</kbd> el icono para enlazar un comentario con uno previo, que se encuentra a la derecha de cada mensaje.

    [image: enlazar respuesta]
  - También hay autocompletado, al escribir `@` seguido de 1 o más letras, aparecen los posibles usuarios. Si uno solo coincide, se puede autocompletar con <kbd>tab</kbd>.
- estuviste en esa sala en los últimos días. La cantidad de días [depende de cómo te hayan nombrado](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/938):

  - Si estuviste en los últimos 7 días y usaron `@NombreUsuario` (*coincidencia exacta*)
  - Si estuviste en los últimos 2 días y usaron `@Nombre` (*primer nombre - límite de palabra*)
  - Si estuviste en los últimos 2 días y usaron `@Nom` (*parte del nombre, mínimo 3 caracteres*), -siempre y cuando no haya otro usuario que coincida exactamente con `Nom` y haya estado en los últimos 7 días o alguien como `Nom Usuario` que coincida con el primer nombre y haya estado en los últimos 2 días.
  - Una respuesta explícita a un comentario (enlazando con la flecha) **siempre** genera un ping.
- no haya sido marcada como vista antes de que el sistema te la envíe. Se marca cuando:

  - visitas un enlace directo a ese mensaje de chat.
  - haciendo click en el número de mensajes que te aparece al lado de tu avatar en el chat para indicarte que tenés mensajes no vistos.
  - diciendo algo en esa sala.
- no hayas seleccionado *ignorar* al usuario (se puede ver a quiénes estás ignorando en tu perfil de chat).

**Ejemplo de notificaciones:**

[image: Notificación de chat]

A diferencia de los comentarios en el sitio principal, en el chat se pueden notificar a múltiples usuarios.

La notificación va a llegar a tu bandeja a los ~15 minutos o, si dentro de tu perfil de usuario de chat activaste la opción *Quicker notifications*, casi inmediatamente.

[image: Preferencias de usuario de chat]

No obstante, no recomendaría activarlo porque es un poco molesto tener tantas notificaciones mientras estás activo en una sala... Pero eso va a gusto personal.

- Tu perfil de usuario de chat está en https://chat.stackexchange.com, seleccionando tu nombre en la barra superior. Las opciones están en la pestaña *prefs*.

Las **notificaciones de escritorio** son totalmente independientes del resto de las notificaciones. -Se pueden tener apagadas y aún así te van a llegar a tu bandeja de entrada. Estas notificaciones funcionan exclusivamente cuando estás presente en una sala.

Además, también hay **notificaciones de sonido**, que se pueden habilitar o modificar en la parte superior de cada sala para que emitan un sonido cuando te mencionan, cuando hay un mensaje nuevo en la sala que está visible, o con mensajes en cualquier sala en la que estés.

[image: Icono Notificaciones de sonido]

---

Referencias:

- [FAQ del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) (*en inglés*)
- Hay muchísimos scripts hechos por usuarios que actúan sobre el chat en [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com)
- La aplicación [Stack Exchange para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) o [Stack Exchange para iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) te permite recibir estas notificaciones en el celular